# Find the circumference

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

[image]

A,B,C, are points on the circle. Point D is the center of the circle. Chord AB is $6\sqrt{2}$. Segment AB and Segment BC is perpendicular.

Can I find the circumference of the given circle, using the given information above only?

I tried this problem, but I made a conclusion that I need an extra piece of information. How do you guys think?

Comment: what do you mean with find the circumference? find the perimeter, radius or what?

Comment: circumference is perimeter of a circle, which you get by radius multiplied by 2pi

Comment: If you have AB. Also AD = DB and the triangle ADB is rectangle, so you can get radius

Comment: How can you set triangle ADB to be a rectangle? Rectangle is a quadrilateral..

Comment: I'm assuming english isn't Eduardo's native language and he meant $\triangle ADB$ is right-angled.  (A rectangle in english is a quadrilateral).  But we are *NOT* told that $\triangle ADB$ has a right angle.  We are told $AB\perp BC$ (which is true for all circles) but we are not told $AD\perp DB$.

Comment: @fleablood true, the draw seems to be $AB = BC$, my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$AB \perp BC$ doesn't tell us anything.  That would be true of *any* circle (assuming that $A,D,C$ are colinear and $D$ is the center [so $ADC$ is a diameter).

So all this tells us is that the circle has a chord of $6\sqrt 2$ but *any* circle with a diameter of $6\sqrt 2$ will have a chord of $6\sqrt 2$ so all we can conclude is the diameter is at least $6\sqrt 2$.

If we know some more information such as $AC\perp DB$ or $AB = BC$ (btw $AC\perp DB \iff AB=BC$) then we could solve it.  Are you sure the problem was written correctly?  Perhaps the book mad an error and we were suppose to be told $AD \perp DB$?

If that *were* the case then as $AD,DB, DC$ are equal length radii and $\triangle ADB$ is right triangle we have $AD^2 + DB^2 = (6\sqrt 2)^2$ and that's easily solved that $AD = 6$.

Comment: Thank you @fleablood. Yes, the problem that I posted is an exact copy of the problem that I found from my student's workbook. And I also checked the intended answer, using the answer key that came along with the workbook (without solution manual). Then ineed the answer was 12$\pi$, meaning AD = 6. What I believe at this point is that the original author of the problem kinda forgot to put an extra information. Anyway, thank you for reply!

Comment: Textbooks contain errors occasionally.  I think that is the case here.  $AB\perp BC$ is irrelevant so I'm inclined to thing they mean $AD \perp DB$.  Or maybe $AB = BC$ was meant to be given.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct.  You know that AC is a diameter but ABC could be a right triangle of any proportion between the legs.  The drawing seems to have AB=BC but you are not given that.

Comment: Right. My student made a strong assumption that AB=BC. However, it is not stated in the problem, nor we have any clues that help us derive AB-BC.

Comment: "You know that AC is a diameter" - correct me if I'm wrong but if we don't know whether AB=BC, then we don't know that AC is a diameter either. Nor that AD and DC are collinear.

Comment: @Jam I believe we can say that AC is a diameter since A and C are the points on the circle and AB and BC are perpendicular. Refer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle if needed.

Comment: It's well known that for any diameter and any third point the inscribed angle is a right one.  And vice versa if a chord and a third point form an inscribed right angle then the cord is a diameter.  But if one wants to be picky we do not know that $A,D,C$ are co-linear.  Rule of thumb is that in drawings you can assume appearance of colinearity and order are colinearity and order but appearence of lengths and angles can't be.

Comment: @fleablood Thank you for the comment. However, I cannot picture a situation where A,D,C are not co-linear while AB and BC are perpendicular and A,B,C are the points on a circle and D is the center of such a circle.

Comment: @fleablood:  we know AC is a diameter and D is the center of the circle, so A, D, C are colinear

Comment: Oh... you are right.  If $AB$ and $BC$ are perpendicular than the arc $ABC$ is a semi-circle and $AC$ is a diameter.  And if $D$ is the center it will be colinear.  That was a silly oversight.

Comment: @fleablood If an inscribed angle is 90 degrees, then its central angle must be 180, since central angle is twice larger than its inscribed angle. The only way to have 180 degrees angle is having AC to be the diameter, or in other words, A,C,D are co-linear isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is an if and only if statement.  Maybe I expressed it badly.  $AB\perp BC \iff AC$ is a diameter.

Comment: .. so we have $\triangle ADB$ is isosceles with a base of $6\sqrt 2$ and sides of the radius and $\triangle BDC$ is isosceles with the sides of the radius but any possible length base.  From that... all we can conclude is $AC > 6\sqrt 2$.  That's it.  Unless we make further assumptions.

Comment: You're all right; my mistake. $AC$ is a diameter and $A,D,C$ are collinear.